# change only works for the first row in a table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am selecting an item from a select-option tag in a table to populate records from a database to fill another input field, but unfortunately, it only works for the first table row. When I add another table row with jquery, it does not work in the new added table row.

```
        <table class="table table-borderd table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>

                    <th>Discount %</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary addmore" value="+"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="itemlist2" class="detailss">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select class="select-product form-control"  name="product_name[]">
                          <option value="">
                  </option>
                     <?php
                    foreach ($product as $key ):
                      ?>
                     <option value="<?php echo $key['id']  ?>">
                       <?php echo $key['product_name'] ?>
                     </option>
                    <?php  endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td>   
                        <input type="text" name="price[]"  class="price form-control" value="">
                   </td>

                    <td><input type="text"  name="quantity[]" class="form-control"></td>
                    <td><input type="text"  name="discount[]" class="form-control"></td>
                    <td><input type="text"  name="total[]" class="form-control"></td> 
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

The script that add new row to table

```
<script>
    var i=$('#itemlist2 tr').length;
    $(".addmore").on('click',function(){
        html = '<tr>';
        html += '<td><select class="select-product form-control" name="product_name[]">  <option value=""> </option><?php foreach ($product as $key ): ?><option value="<?php echo $key['id']  ?>"><?php echo $key['product_name'] ?></option><?php  endforeach; ?></select></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="price[]"  class="price form-control" value=""></td>';
        html += ' <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control"></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text"  name="discount[]" class="form-control"></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text"  name="total[]" class="form-control"></td>';
       html += '</tr>';
        $('#itemlist2').append(html);
        i++;
    });
</script>
```

The onchange function with ajax

```
        <script>
$(function() {

$(document).on('change', '.select-product',  function(){
          $(this).change(function(){
            var id=$(this).val();
            var dataString = 'id='+ id;
            $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "<?php echo site_url('/product/view_data'); ?>",
                   data: dataString,
                   cache: false,
                   success: function(html){
  $('.price').parent().parent().find('.price').val(html); 
                   } 
            });

          });

       });

    });

</script>
```

Thanks  for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use delegate for dynamically added element. For example

```
$(document).delegate( ".select-product", "change", function() {
      $(this).change(function(){
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;
        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "<?php echo site_url('/product/view_data'); ?>",
               data: dataString,
               cache: false,
               success: function(html){

                alert(html);
                    //  $("#price").val(html);
               } 
        });

      });

   });

});
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Sir, My code almost working except duplicate value in every field. Example, when I select product the ajax value set up every time every row where I declare ID price $("#price").val(html). I want when I will select first row of product then the price will set up in first row of price box and when I will select product from 2nd row then price will show on 2nd row of price box. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Sir, can you help me. I am suffering that from last 8days.

Comment: you should use "price" as class instead of id and then use this $(this).parent().parent().find('.price').val(html); to set price for corresponding row.     Sorry for delay

Comment: sir, i have changed but it updates multiple price box together.

Comment: sir, I have Updated both html and ajax code. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

New added elements does not have the event binding.

The quickest fix is just change your event binding code from

```
$('input').change(function () {
  // Do some stuff.
});
```

to

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
  // Do some stuff.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these following lines:

```
html += '<td><select class="select-product form-control" id="product" ....
```

and

```
var id=$("#product").val();
```

You are assigning an id to multiple rows and trying to get the values using **id** which is unique. That's why you are getting the data for first row only.

To solve this, refer it using **class** and **$(this)** to get the value of current instance.

Comment: I have changed but if i click on multiple select element the value is set on first row.